# Why was the swearing taken out of "Gods and Monsters" in American horror story?

Tags: soundtrack, censorship, american-horror-story

In American Horror story: Freak show Elsa Mars sings a version of Lana Del Rey's "Gods and Monsters" in which, amongst other things, all of the bad language is changed for more... suitable(?) language. Why is this given that the episode itself and series as a whole is rife with such language and worse in terms of sex and violence (and violent sex)?

**My uneducated guess was that it was used in pre-watershed publicity but why would you publicize this then?**

Elsa Mars version is awesome for those who don't remember it: